# Controller not a function got undefined error message angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

I am a beginner with MEAN Stack development. I was trying out to play around with some angular stuff but got completely messed up the the controllers.
Here is my main html file

```
<!--main.html-->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Chirp</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/chirpApp.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css">
  </head>
  <body ng-app="chirpApp">
    <div id='main' class="container" ng-controller="mainController">
      <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
        <div class="clearfix">
          <form ng-Submit="post()">
            <input required type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name" ng-model="newPost.created_by" /> 
            <textarea required class="form-control" maxlength="200" rows="3" placeholder="Say something" ng-model="newPost.text"></textarea>
            <input class="btn submit-btn pull-right" type="submit" value="Chirp!" />
          </form>
          <div id="post-stream">
            <h4>Chirp Feed</h4>
                <div class="post" ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'created_at':true" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'"> 
                  <p>{{post.text}}</p>
                <small>Posted by @{{post.created_by}}</small>
                <small class="pull-right">{{post.created_at | date:"h:mma 'on' MMM d, y"}}</small>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have created another html file for registration. here is the code for it.

```
<!--register.html-->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Chirp</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/chirpApp.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css">
  </head>
  <body ng-app="chirpApp">
    <div id='main' class="container" ng-controller="authController">
      <form class="form-auth" ng-submit="register()">
        <h2>Register</h2>
        <p class="text-warning">{{error_message}}</p>
        <input type="username" ng-model="user.username" placeholder="Username" class="form-control"><br>
        <input type="password" ng-model="user.password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have created two separate controllers for registration and posts. the first controller works nicely but whenever I am trying to add a second controller I am getting an error message. Here is the code for my controllers.

```
//chirpApp.js
var app = angular.module('chirpApp', []);

app.controller('mainController', function($scope){
  $scope.posts = [];
  $scope.newPost = {created_by: '', text: '', created_at: ''};

  $scope.post = function(){
    $scope.newPost.created_at = Date.now();
    $scope.posts.push($scope.newPost);
    $scope.newPost = {created_by: '', text: '', created_at: ''};
  };
});

app.controller('authController', function($scope){
  $scope.user = {username: '', password: ''};
  $scope.error_message = '';

  $scope.login = function(){
    //placeholder until authentication is implemented
    $scope.error_message = 'login request for ' + $scope.user.username;
  };

  $scope.register = function(){
    //placeholder until authentication is implemented
    $scope.error_message = 'registeration request for ' + $scope.user.username;
  };
});
```

I am getting the following error in the chrome console :

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/ng/areq?p0=authController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:6:453
    at tb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:18:250)
    at Oa (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:18:337)
    at $get (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:61:288)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:48:476
    at q (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:7:367)
    at S (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:48:342)
    at h (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:43:59)
    at h (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:43:76)
```

main.html works fine and the data is being binded successfully. 
The issue is with the register.html page. I suppose the authController is not getting binded

Can anyone suggest me the best way of implementing the same? And why the controller is getting undefined?

Comment: What is the actual error message? Also, could you describe the problem better? When does the error occur? What works and what doesn't work?

Comment: Hey arindam, I just tried out your code and its working fine without any error. Please check in chrome dev tool if your JS file is loaded correctly(not throwing 404)because I tried with Inline javascript.

Comment: @Phil : he has clearly mentioned "And why the controller is getting undefined?" And IMHO we should not discourage new developers from posting questions.

Comment: @prashanth yes but when does the error occur? On `main.html`, `register.html` or both? Which controller is undefined? I only asked for more information, not sure how you equate that to *discouraging*

Comment: @Phil It was not for you. Someone gave down vote for the question.

Comment: @prashanth Well, saying you have an error message without providing that error message is a sure-fire way to attract downvotes on SO

Comment: Thanks guys. I have provided the console error that I am witnessing.

Comment: @prashanth did you get to see the dynamic message after entering the username and password in register.html? It doesn't work at my end :'(

Comment: @ArindamDawn after submitting its gives me "registeration request for asdasd" where asdasd is username.

Comment: then its working at your end. I think the js file is not getting loaded properly. I'll troubleshoot the same. Anyways thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the plunker of your files

http://embed.plnkr.co/6jNXImBddYqjK23FCWUy/preview

Your application works as expected. Please check your core files is loaded or not.

Hope this helps

```
your code
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following checklist:

1. angularjs lib is included in
2. ng-app=".." directive is in index.html
3. ..path/to/module and other controllers in  index.html
4. module and controllers defined correctly (spelling, syntax etc)

**Controller example (if not using global angular var:**

```
    app.controller('AppController', ['$http', '$scope', '$log',
        function($http, $scope, $log) {
          // TODO: implement
        }
    ]);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new controller with the AngularJS Controller Sub-Generator you have to reboot Grunt.